# can we write data in firebase database through SMS?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-messaging

is it possible to write data in the firebase database through SMS?
I have to **develop** an android app in which I want to write data directly to the database through SMS. The user will send SMS and it will be written to the database.
Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in connection between the Firebase Realtime Database and an SMS gateway. If you want your users to be able to write to the database by sending an SMS/text message, you will have to build this connection yourself.

You'd typically use a SMS provider (Twillio, Nexmo, Clicksend, etc) to receive the messages on your behalf. In their portal you then set up a so-called webhook, which is a URL they call when they receive a text message for you. You could wire up that webhook to Cloud Functions, where you then receive the text message, parse its contents, and write to the database.

Here is a tutorial to [Respond to SMS Messages with Twilio and Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-twilio-sms), with just Google Cloud Functions (so not using Firebase/Realtime Database yet), that show the basic flow. There are probably other useful tutorials too in this [list of search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=twillio+receive+text+cloud+fuctions+firebase+database).